# Fix y-coordinate when producing igraph layout

Tags: r, layout, igraph

I am trying to produce a tree-like diagram using R package `igraph`. I start with an adjacency matrix Y that looks like this:

```
Y <- matrix(c(1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,
              1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,
              0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
              0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1),
              ncol=25)
```

Then I create the graph using

```
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(Y,mode="undirected",diag=F)
```

Now I want to plot a tree-like diagram with the first node being on top of the tree, for which I do

```
L <- layout.reingold.tilford(g,root=1)
plot.igraph(g,layout=L)
```

The result looks pretty close to what I am looking for, but now I would like to use custom y-coordinates for the vertices. The reason is that I want the y axis to have meaning: I have a `score` value for each vertex, and I want the y coordinate to be proportional to that score. Of course I could do it by simply using

```
L[,2] <- score
```

The problem is that by doing that I mess up the plot, getting overlapping vertices and intersecting edges, which is undesirable. I can solve it by manually adjusting the x-coordinates with `tkplot`, but eventually I will need to automatically produce several plots and manually checking them one by one is just not feasible.

So the question is, is there any way to get an "optimal" tree graph representation using pre-defined y-coordinates for the vertices?

Hope I have been clear enough. Thanks in advance for your time!

J

EDIT: This is what I get if I `dput` my graph variable `g` (note that the `scores` have been added as vertex attributes and can be accesed through `V(g)$scores`)

```
> dput(g)    
structure(list(25, FALSE, c(1, 2, 5, 4, 6, 3, 12, 8, 11, 13, 
14, 17, 7, 9, 19, 20, 10, 18, 22, 24, 15, 16, 21, 23), c(0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 13, 13, 
16, 16), c(0, 1, 5, 3, 2, 4, 12, 7, 13, 16, 8, 6, 9, 10, 20, 
21, 11, 17, 14, 15, 22, 18, 23, 19), c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23), 
    c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
    16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24), c(0, 3, 5, 7, 9, 12, 
    14, 14, 16, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 22, 22, 22, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24), list(c(1, 0, 1), structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
        structure(list(name = c("GO:0008150", "GO:0050896", "GO:0044699", 
        "GO:0044767", "GO:0051716", "GO:0016043", "GO:0002544", 
        "GO:0071822", "GO:0048513", "GO:0007044", "GO:0007517", 
        "GO:0030855", "GO:0006816", "GO:0007165", "GO:0042178", 
        "GO:0007169", "GO:0009966", "GO:0070458", "GO:0090131", 
        "GO:0007052", "GO:0006335", "GO:2000587", "GO:0045653", 
        "GO:0070372", "GO:0003257"), scores = c(0, 0.301029995663981, 
        0.301029995663981, 0.602059991327962, 0.602059991327962, 
        0.602059991327962, 0.778151250383644, 0.778151250383644, 
        1, 1.04139268515822, 1.07918124604762, 1.07918124604762, 
        1.11394335230684, 1.11394335230684, 1.14612803567824, 
        1.20411998265592, 1.23044892137827, 1.25527250510331, 
        1.25527250510331, 1.27875360095283, 1.39794000867204, 
        1.50514997831991, 1.63346845557959, 1.70757017609794, 
        1.96378782734556), color = c("black", "black", "black", 
        "black", "black", "black", "red", "black", "black", "red", 
        "red", "red", "red", "black", "red", "red", "black", 
        "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red"
        )), .Names = c("name", "scores", "color")), list()), 
    <environment>), class = "igraph")
```

Comment: Could you `dput` your data? You probably want `layout_with_sugiyama`, passing `scores` to the `layers` argument. But can't test this out without the data.

Comment: I just edited the question adding the `dput` of my `g` variable. I also tried doing `L<-layout_with_sugiyama(g,layers=V(g)$scores)` and then plotting with `plot.igraph(g,layout=L$layout)`, and while it does indeed place the vertices at the y-locations specified by `scores`, I'm still getting some ugly intersections among edges...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `layout_with_sugiyama` didn't work,  I am going to propose more of a hack, 
or rather two hacks, one building on the other.

First, a little cleaning. Using your dput version of g, I get the warning

> ```
> graph was created by an old(er) igraph version.
> Call upgrade_graph() on it to use with the current igraph version
> For now we convert it on the fly...
> ```

So I start with    `g = upgrade_graph(g)`
Next, when I plot your graph,  I find it hard to read because of the 
navy text on black nodes. So, I am changing your nodes to gray. 
You can leave this out if you like.
`V(g)$color[V(g)$color == "black"] = "#888888"`

Now we need to layout the graph.  I will start as you did with
Reingold-Tilford
`L <- layout.reingold.tilford(g,root=1)`
But this does not use your `scores`. Of course,  a layout, just gives 
x-y positions for the nodes,  so hack number one is to just over-write
the y values with your scores.

```
L2 = L
L2[,2] = V(g)$scores 
plot(g,layout=L2)
```

The plot is a bit crowded into the center of the plotting area. So I will 
get rid of the margins.

```
par(mar=rep(0,4))
plot(g,layout=L2)
```

[image: First plot of graph]

This is not too bad, but a few of the node labels still overlap.
Hack number two is that I will just move these "by hand".

```
L3 = L2
L3[18,1] = -2.2
L3[19,1] = -1.1
L3[12,1] = 0
L3[13,1] = 1
plot(g,layout=L3)
```

At this point, the heights are proportional to your score and no labels overlap.

[image: Cleaner Plot]